# How to get the value by calling an overloaded conversion operator ()

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading

What is the proper way to call `()` operator overloaded to return a float

```
class MyClass {
public:
    operator float () const {
        return m_some_float_value;
    }

private:
    float m_some_float_value       
}
```

Comment: That's not `operator()`, it's a conversion operator. It will be called whenever you class is required to be a `float`. I think there should be a duplicate somewhere...

Comment: Okay. Does this mean that I cannot at all get the value of `m_some_float_value` in outside `MyClass`?

Comment: `MyClass myObject; float f = myObject;` will put `m_some_float_value` in `f`. As well as calling a function taking `float`, using `static_cast` or any other way that converts one type to another, when the result type should be `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  operator float() const {
    return m_some_float_value;
  };

private:
  float m_some_float_value = 1.0f;   // initialize with 1.0f for
                                     // demo purposes                                    
};

int main() {
  MyClass c;
  float x = c; // just do the assignment and
               // the float operator will be called

  // now x contains 1.0f
}
```